# Ошибка при подключении к БД  login failed for user

Tags: asp.net, c#, sql

Asp.net.

При загрузке страницы подключаюсь к БД и на строке:

```
InfoPage infop = dc.InfoPages.FirstOrDefault(u => u.InfoTitle == "AboutAuthor");
```

выдает ошибку:

> login failed for user

Что не так? Вот строка подключения:

```
<add name="InterDesConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=InterDes;Integrated Security=False"
```

Помогите разобраться, кажется пароль нигде не стоит. С чем это связано?

Comment: Попробуйте ``Integrated Security=True``

Comment: пробовал, тоже самое

Comment: На локальной машине я использую ``Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте что стоит в конфигурации сервера. Named pipes enable нужно по-моему.